# Alternative to watch which support colors

Tags: bash, utilities, watch

I have a command (`phpunit`) which has a colored output. According to the `watch`, command I should be able to use the `--color` flag to allow color rendering to pass through. However, this isn't working. Is there any other ways of solving this?

Comment: Are you sure that is not the command that do not output colors when stdout is not a terminal? Try `phpunit | cat`

Comment: While @enzotib probably is right, a [BASH script could be used as a workaround](http://excess.org/article/2009/07/watch1-bash-unicode/) anyway.

Comment: `phpunit | cat` didn't work unfortunately. However the bash script approach worked great. Thanks!

Comment: @netbrain: as supposed, the fact that `phpunit | cat` do not work is a symptom that the problem is in `phpunit` and not in `watch`.

Comment: On some common Unixes (Such as Snow Leopard), `--color` is not a valid flag for `watch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phpunit | cat` didn't work (signalling that this is not a problem with `watch` but the `phpunit`  command).

As an alternative, the following bash script approach worked great for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    (echo -en '\033[H'
        CMD="$@"
        bash -c "$CMD" | while read LINE; do 
            echo -n "$LINE"
            echo -e '\033[0K' 
        done
        echo -en '\033[J') | tac | tac 
    sleep 2 
done
```

Usage:

```
$ botch my-command
```

Comment: Please update your answer with more details. As it is, if the comments on your question get removed, it is not very helpful. Include at least the link to that script you're using, or better: whatever you ended up doing exactly so it can help future visitors if that link goes dead.

Comment: @netbrain also `phpunit | cat` wasnt supposed to work. It was supposed to be a test to prove `watch` wasn't removing the colors, but rather `phpunit` wasnt outputting them when it noticed that STDOUT wasnt a TTY.

Comment: `phpunit --colors=always ` produces color output when not directly connected to a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
watch --color phpunit9 --colors=always
```

Note that there's a color[s] flag on *both* watch *and* phpunit

phpunit will disable terminal colour sequences if it detects that it's in a pipe situation, unless you force it to output colour with `--colours=always`. watch will not honour colours without `--color` so you need both.

(just noted that this is the same as Robert Waelder's answer, though leaving mine here as it specifically addresses OP's command, phpunit)

Answer (score 0):

Here my implementation, it's a bash script but it's very easy convert it to function (to change 'exit' to 'return')

```
#!/bin/bash

trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c()
{
    echo -en "\033[?7h" #Enable line wrap
    echo -e "\033[?25h" #Enable cursor
    exit 0
}

function print_usage()
{
    echo
    echo '  Usage: cwatch [sleep time] "command"'
    echo '  Example: cwatch "ls -la"'
    echo
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ] || [ $# -gt 2 ]
then
    print_usage
    exit 1
fi

SLEEPTIME=1
if [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
    SLEEPTIME=${1}
    if [[ $SLEEPTIME = *[[:digit:]]* ]]
    then
        shift
    else
        print_usage
        exit 1
    fi
fi

CMD="${1}"
echo -en "\033[?7l" #Disable line wrap
echo -en "\033[?25l" #Disable cursor
while (true)
do

    (echo -en "\033[H" #Sets the cursor position where subsequent text will begin
    echo -e "Every ${SLEEPTIME},0s: '\033[1;36m${CMD}\033[0m'\033[0K"
    echo -e "\033[0K" #Erases from the current cursor position to the end of the current line
    BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc bash -O expand_aliases -c "${CMD}" | while IFS='' read -r LINE 
    do
        echo -n "${LINE}"
        echo -e "\033[0K" #Erases from the current cursor position to the end of the current line
    done
    #echo -en "\033[J") | tac | tac #Erases the screen from the current line down to the bottom of the screen
    echo -en "\033[J") #Erases the screen from the current line down to the bottom of the screen
    sleep ${SLEEPTIME}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having this same problem and after playing around with it for awhile, using

```
watch --color dmesg --color=always
```

outputted dmesg in full color as expected. so it might help to be extra explicit with color parameters on any commands fed into watch.